# Search for deprecated PHP tags

Tags: php, linux, cpanel

I have a cPanel server running 5.2.17 with a few hundred accounts.

I need to update to at least PHP 5.4 and need to search for deprecated functions within all accounts hosted.

Is there a way to batch search for all deprecated functions in 5.3/5.4 so these can be resolved before upgrade.

Comment: What are you going to do with this information?

Comment: @sectus OP says he's going to use it to resolve deprecated functions. He's doing this so when he updates, he won't get a fatal error.

Comment: @DaveChen, resolve? Edit user code or what? Also, deprecated errors are not fatal.

Comment: It's going to be a lot easier to pinpoint where the use of deprecated functions are within source files to resolve them, fix them, by either putting in a replacement function or implementing another method. I imagine there's a lot of people going through the same thing, but I vtc because it's not really asking about code, but rather a link to a library.

Comment: @DaveChen, error.log is build-in tool to pinpoint.

Comment: @sectus It doesn't account for all the code that can be run.

Answer (score 2):

The script described in this article automates testing for depreciated PHP functions. A download link is in the article.

```
http://techblog.wimgodden.be/2012/03/04/php-5-4-compatibility-checks-using-php_codesniffer/
```

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated features is not really harmful. You could [suppress deprecated errors](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.error-reporting.php).

But [backward incompatible changes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php) could ruin the code logic and execution process.

Anyway. The most of deprecated features is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php) [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.deprecated.php).

You could try just to search for them.

You cannot find with 100%(and without mistakes) all deprecated features because of PHP nature.

Comment: Automated PHP compatibility testing: http://techblog.wimgodden.be/2010/06/24/automated-php-5-3-compatibility-testing-for-your-old-code/

Comment: @Len_D , please, comment the question. Or create an answer.

Comment: At some point you have to be aware that PHP developers will probably remove the depreciated functions fromt he language. So I do not agree that "depreciated functions are not really harmful". They represent a time bomb and risk to the continued operation of your systems that are built on them.

Comment: @Len_D, you know, it's strange to take care about deprecated features without mentioning incompatible changes.

Comment: You're right. It is incumbent on the developer to to ensure compatibility during the testing cycle.